# Vexing Regex Using stringr [next line query]

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have made so many attempts at this and must now turn to you. I've seen related posts here on SO but none help. I'm vexed as to why I can't get a list of instruments, which seem to appear on the line following the word `Instruments:`!

```
library(RCurl);library(XML);library(rvest);library(dplyr);library(stringr)

A<-"https://www.google.com/search?q=lester+young&oq=lester+young&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l3.1767j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"

result<-A %>%
    read_html()%>%
    html_nodes(xpath="//span")%>%html_text()

# Parse `result` with regex
instruments<-str_extract(result,"(.*Instruments:\n.*)")
instruments
dob<-str_extract(result,".*(Born: \n.*)")
dob
```

'result' looks like this, in part:

[38] "Lester Willis Young, nicknamed \"Pres\" or \"Prez\", was an American jazz tenor saxophonist and occasional clarinetist.\nComing to prominence while a member of Count Basie's orchestra, Young was one of the most influential players on his instrument. Wikipedia"
[39] "Born: "
[40] "August 27, 1909, Woodville, MS"
[41] "Died: "
[42] "March 15, 1959, New York City, NY"
[43] "Nickname: "
[44] "Prez"
[45] "Instruments: "
[46] "Tenor saxophone, clarinet"

While it's possible to use `instruments<-result[46]` for this webpage, the HTML scraping yields instrument and dob information on different lines for different searches.

Ultimately, I would like to see "Piano" in the `instruments` object and a date of birth in the `dob` object.

Thank you...

Comment: Show us some of your sample text

Comment: You certainly have included some libraries before using the above code.  Could you please add the `library` statements in your code so that we know what to include?

Comment: I seems that "Instruments" has a space between `:` and `\n`. Try `"(.*Instruments:\s+?\n.*)"`

Comment: I get Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(.*Instruments:\s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Get the index of "Instruments:" and then print the next entry. Of course, if the page format changes, this may not work.

```
> i <- as.integer(grep("Instruments:",result))
> print(result[i+1])
[1] "Tenor saxophone, clarinet"
```

or this:

```
> result_all <- paste(result,collapse="\n")
> str_extract(result_all,"(Instruments:.*\\n.*)")
[1] "Instruments: \nTenor saxophone, clarinet"
```

Comment: the collapse argument is what was needed.  Thanks!